# Websocket connector as a Listener

Tags: websocket, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I wanted to connect to Websocket listener. I can connect successfully via web socket inbound message connector by providing HTTP/HTTPS server details in configuration but our requirement is we need to listen the messages from Websocket connector as a listener.
Am unable to connect to Websocket listener (On new inbound connector) if I provide server details which will be http listener am unable to do it.
For example-
"wss://api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud/test" we want to include this url with wss url, so that we read messages from HOST :api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud. Could you please help us where should we provide the config details in websocket listener config.

I can get messages from wss://api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud/test if we add configuration details in client settings through Open Outbound Socket connector . But the request is to use the websocket inbound connector.
How to use websocket (Connector) as a listener.
Please guide me how can we achieve?

Comment: When you say that you want to use use web socket as a Listener, you are saying that you want to use the web socket connector as a **source** or a **trigger** of the flow? Am I right?

Comment: When you say you are unable to connect using `wss://api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud/test`, can you tell what is the error / problem that you are facing. If you can provide with the configuration that you have configured then it will be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: I can connect to "wss://api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud/test" url using authentication and am getting results too but the issue here is i want to connect as a source Websocket listener and then do the integration.

Comment: how to trigger the flow via websocket listener.
I am triggering my flow through a scheduler but requirement is to trigger it through websocket listener. below is the code. Please help me out with some solution
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Harshank, am unable to add code for some reason is there any way i can share you code here, will tell you how am actually working-
scheduler -> getting access token-> pass that token to "Open outbound socket" -> getting results
now in place of scheduler i need to put Websocket listener.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve?
*clientA calls your mule websocket -> This triggers mule flow -> flow gets token and pass token to another server (server B) via websockets -> after you connect to server B, server B sends some data via websocket -> Your flow wants to send this data back to Client A ?*

 Is this your requirement

Comment: Yes... absolutely.
The initial part is not happening "clientA calls your mule websocket -> This triggers mule flow " later after this step it gets executed.
But the initial part am unable to implement.

Comment: Understood, Does the Client A sends a message after connecting to the mule websocket? or does it just connects and you have to respond to that connection itself? Let's discuss this over chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244716/discussion-between-harshank-bansal-and-auro

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is that the communication with WebSockets is bidirectional. This means that, besides you are the client and connect to the server using `Open Outbound Socket`, or you are the server and use `On New Inbound Connection`, you have both operations available to interact: `Send` and `On New Inbound Message`.

So, in your case, once you do a `Open Outbound Socket`, then you need a flow with the `On New Inbound Message` source to capture the messages sent by the server.

I recommend playing with these examples to get more XP on the WebSocket connector https://docs.mulesoft.com/websockets-connector/1.0/websockets-connector-examples

Comment: Thank you for the Response.
I need to first listen through websocket listener then I need to integrate with open outbound socket connector.
right now am implementing using a scheduler as a listener and later integrating with open outbound socket which is successful but the requirement is I need to listen from Websocket Connector as a listener and later integrate with Open outbound socket connector.  which am unable to do Please help me out...

Comment: Let me see if I understood. Your Mule app is in the middle of a client and a WebSocket server? So the client connects to you and then you connect to the server, both using WebSocket?

Comment: Yes @ 
Jorge Garcia

Comment: Yes @ 
Jorge Garcia
I need to first connect via Websocket listener as a source and then connect to the client and get the reports from Websocket connector (open outbound connector).
I am trying but unable to call the flow... how should i do..

Comment: right now working with this approach scheduler -> getting access token-> pass that token to "Open outbound socket" -> getting results in place of scheduler i need to put Websocket listener.

Comment: From you last comment I understand that your Mule app is the client. Client first hit `wss://api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud/test` unsing HTTP, then `api-testurl-1` validates the session and respond to upgrade to Web Sockets. This is what you are doning now with the scheduler, which is right. You need to start the connection at some point, it's not automatically stablished by the connector. Then, you willl have a flow with `On New Inbound Message` where the server, `api-testurl-1`, can push the data. That flow is what you refer as `Websocket listener`.

Comment: Here, Mule app listens through a listener which is a Scheduler then gets the access token from Http requester then hits  "wss://api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud/test" url and gets the response. which is successful and working.
I need to do is I need to listen in place of scheduler is Websocket listener then get the access token and then ""wss://api-testurl-1.xyz.name.cloud/test" url to hit and get the response.
Please help me resolving this will be a great help

Comment: So, if you replace now the scheduler with 'On New Inbound Connection' or with 'On New Inbound Message', always using a new global configuration (in this case acting as server, not client), what is the issues? What is missing?

Comment: Issue is resolved I have added as a listener scheduler and then making connection and listening the messages.
Thank you for your time and effort appreciate it :)